# Getting a Python Object from JSON

Tags: python, json

What is the best way to get a Python Object (with custom objects as attributes) from JSON?

I'm using a JSON object as configuration, like this:

```py
conf = {
    [
        {
            'column_name': 'Period start time', 
            'validators': [
                {
                    'validator': 'DateFormatValidation',
                    'arguments': {'format': '%m.%d.%Y %H:%M:%S'}
                },
                {
                    'validator': 'IsRequiredValidation',
                    'arguments': {}
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            'column_name': 'value', 
            'validators': [
                {
                    'validator': 'IsNumberValidation',
                    'arguments': {}
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to convert to a Python object, something like this:

```py
{[
    Column('Period start time', [DateFormatValidation('%m.%d.%Y %H:%M:%S'), IsRequiredValidation()]),
    Column('value', [IsNumberValidation()]),
]}
```

In this example `Column`, `DateFormatValidation`, `IsNumberValidation` and `IsRequiredValidation` are classes.

Any clue about the way to proceed?

## UPDATE

---

Yes guys there was an issue with the json, here is the code based on your guiding discarding error handling:

```py
STR_CONFIG = '''
    [
        {
            "column_name":"Period start time",
            "validators": [
                {
                    "validator": "DateFormatValidation",
                    "arguments": {"date_format": "%m.%d.%Y %H:%M:%S"}
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "column_name":"RNC name"
        }
    ]
'''

conf = json.loads(STR_CONFIG)

column_list = []
validator_list = []

available_validators = {
    "DateFormatValidation": DateFormatValidation,
    "IsNumberValidation": IsNumberValidation,
    "IsRequiredValidation": IsRequiredValidation,
}

for obj in conf:
    if 'validators' in obj:
        for validator in obj['validators']:
            clase = available_validators[validator['validator']]
            if 'arguments' in validator:
                arguments = validator['arguments']
                validator_list.append(clase(**arguments))
            else:
                validator_list.append(clase())
    column_list.append(Column(obj['column_name'], validator_list))
    validator_list = []

result = column_list
```

It is working great!, but with this approach I see two issues:

1. Implementing a mapping for classes (`available_validators`): I have to take care modifying the code if I create new validators.
2. If I add nested objects to JSON (conf) the code could get a little messy between many `for` and `if`. I was reading about `object_hook` for converting JSON to Python objects but I'm not sure if applies for this case.

Comment: Parse the object into a `dict` using `json.load`. *Then* worry about converting the resulting data structure into what you want, independently of JSON. (In fact, `conf` *is* a Python `dict` already; it doesn't matter if JSON was the original source for the `dict`.)

Comment: Isn't your first portion of ```conf``` not valid json? Where is key before you go into a list?

Comment: Yes, as above. The same time, for 'Period start time', there're two validators, but only first validator shown in you result, does it mean 2nd validator ignored ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all. Your json string is not valid format. Fix it for example usage

```
[
    {
        "column_name": "Period start time",
        "validators": [
            {
                "validator": "DateFormatValidation",
                "arguments": {
                    "format": "%m.%d.%Y %H:%M:%S"
                }
            },
            {
                "validator": "IsRequiredValidation",
                "arguments": {}
            }
        ]
    },
    {
            "column_name": "value", 
            "validators": [
            {
                    "validator": "IsNumberValidation",
                    "arguments": {}
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

You can use python json library to deserialize json.
Then you can use dict and list object to initialize Column, DateFormatValidation, IsNumberValidation and IsRequiredValidation.

But there is some extra skill you need to know.
you need to use python  to create object by string object. The easy way is to establish dict for class collection.
Just put some example for your guideline.

```py
import json


class Column:
    def __init__(self, column_name, list_of_validator):
        self.column_name = column_name
        self.list_of_validator = list_of_validator
        pass

class mapper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cls_dict = {}

    def add_mapping(self, string):
        def decorator(validator):
            self.cls_dict[string] = validator
            return validator
        return decorator

mapping = mapper()


@mapping.add_mapping('DateFormatValidation')
class DateFormatValidation:
    def __init__(self, arguments=None):
        pass

@mapping.add_mapping('IsNumberValidation')
class IsNumberValidation:
    def __init__(self, arguments=None):
        pass

@mapping.add_mapping('IsRequiredValidation')
class IsRequiredValidation:
    def __init__(self, arguments=None):
        pass


with open("conf.json") as json_file:
    conf_obj = json.load(json_file)

validator_list = []
column_list = []

for conf in conf_obj:
    for validator in conf['validators']:
        cls = mapping.cls_dict[validator['validator']]
        try:
            argument = validator['arguments']['format']
        except KeyError:
            argument = None
        validator_list.append(cls(argument))
    column_list.append(Column(conf['column_name'], validator_list))
    validator_list = []
```

---

### Update

If you want to have better way to manage your validator and serializer mapping , you can use decorator to register you relation. I've updated code above.

I assume you want to have most easy way to mapping class name, but it is really not safe. It is better to write a mapper class and register by decorator.

In this case, you can use object_hook with json.loads but you still need to write if and or in object_hook function. You need to have another pythonic way to simply you program.